# How does a control unit work?

Tags: architecture, controls, hardware

I've been trying to learn how computers work since summer, but I haven't found much information on control units. By "how it works", I don't mean "what does it do?". How does it actually do what it does, what does the circuitry of a control unit like, how is that circuitry used to do what a control unit does, etc.. Where could I learn about them?

Comment: Just look up Wikipedia <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_unit>, and the literature there.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get hold of this very old but outstanding book, you will be able to learn this in a crisp manner: Digital Computer Electronics by Albert P. Malvion

The book talks about 3 "simple as possible" computer circuits - first being very simple and the 3rd is closer to Intel 8085. They tell you how an instruction is decoded in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I found this class from MIT did a great job of building up how a computer works: (http://6004.mit.edu/Spring13/).  There are video lectures and lab materials so you can play and build your own computer from the gates up.

It's designed for sophomore college students (so long as you know basic programming, you'll probably be fine).

The first lecture on youtube can be found here (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CvfifZsmpQ4).  It starts from how the basic physical transistors work, and slowly moves all the way up to an actual processor.

You can also get your hands on a ["Computer Architecture"](http://www.amazon.com/s/url=search-alias=stripbooks&field-keywords=computer%20architecture&sprefix=computer+ar,stripbooks&rh=i%3astripbooks,k%3acomputer%20architecture) book, but those will probably skim the lower level stuff and discuss how processors work at a bit higher level (above the "digital abstraction").